# How to plot multi bar char with multi line char on secondary y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Thanks in advance.
I'd like to plot a multi-bar chart on the primary y-axis while plotting multiple lines on the secondary y-axis with a different scale in R. Here is the test data.

```
test.data<-data.frame(TYPE=c("A","B","C","D"), D1=c(20,10,1,1.1), 
      D2=c(40,20,3,2), D3=c(9,30,8,3), D4=c(12,20,3,6), D5=c(30,10,6,3) )
```

I hope it can be displayed like this below.

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

test.data<-data.frame(TYPE=c("A","B","C","D"), D1=c(20,10,1,1.1), 
                      D2=c(40,20,3,2), D3=c(9,30,8,3), D4=c(12,20,3,6), D5=c(30,10,6,3) )


df1 <- test.data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -TYPE) %>% 
  subset(TYPE %in% c("A","B"))


df2 <- test.data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -TYPE) %>% 
  subset(TYPE %in% c("C","D")) 


ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = df1, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = TYPE), position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual("Type", values = c("A" = "#56B4E9", "B" = "#E69F00"))+
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = name, y = value*5,  group = TYPE, col = TYPE)) + 
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = name, y = value*5, group = TYPE, col = TYPE)) +
  scale_color_manual("Type", values = c("C" = "darkgrey", "D" = "black"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "First Axis",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.*1/5, name="Second Axis"))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: How should I set up 'sec_axis' if the secondary axis is not linearly correlated with the primary axis? For example, the range of the primary axis is 0-40, while the secondary can be -1 ~ 1 or -2 ~ 5 dynamically.